# Сайт в FireFox отображается некорректно

Tags: html, css, firefox

Почему сайт в FireFox отображается некорректно? Браузеры на Chronium и Presto отображают страницу как надо.
[image: блок]
[Ссылка на сам сайт](http://rta-customs.ru/)
В FireFox в разделах "Бакалавриат/Специалитет", "Магистратура", "Аспирантура" контент внутри зеленых блоков зажёван.

Comment: у разных браузеров свои первоначальные stylesheet, у вас зеленые беки фиксированного размера, в фоксе `li` элементы выше, поэтому и не влазят.

Comment: Потому что пора кончать прописывать фиксированные размеры элементам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не думаю что проблема в line-height, в разных браузерах шрифт по разному рендерится, и у ФФ текст переносится на новую строку, а так как родительский блок имеет статическую высоту - текст прячется вниз. Для ФФ нужно прописать

```
letter-spacing: -0.01em;
```

но все же я советую убрать статическую высоту с родителя.

Comment: Да, вот это помогло. Текст везде стал виден. Но всё равно есть маленькие косяки с длинной блоков. На днях займусь переделкой сайта, уберу статичную высоту везде.

Answer (score 1):

Дополните высотой строки и будет отображаться одинаково:

```
.data ul li, .data1 ul li {
     line-height: 18px;
}
```

Comment: Прописал. Списки стали одинаковой высоты, но блоки всё равно зажёвываются. Проверил отступы позиционирования, вроде всё правильно. Затем начал мерить линейкой и увидел, что почти все боки расходятся по высоте. Походу нужно прописывать фиксированную высоту для всех элементов.  
Вот посмотрите на картинке - http://i.imgur.com/li4HOI0.jpg

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте прописать стили специально для FireFox:

```
 @-moz-document url-prefix(){  
.class {стили для класса}
#id {стили для id}
 }
```